# How to make your own maple extract?

Tags: flavor

Does anyone have any experience with making your own maple extract?

I am on a low carb diet, so real maple syrup is not an option for me. Again, the solution is of course maple extract, but I am not sure if making maple extract  is possible at all since it would be made from a syrup.

Ideas on how to make maple extract or an other type of maple flavoring substance are welcome as well.

Up till now,  I only managed to make an imitation maple extract from toasted fenugreek seeds (https://www.leaf.tv/articles/how-to-make-maple-extract/). The taste was not bad, but not as close to maple as I would have liked and it turned out ever so slightly bitter.

Comment: Hey, thank you for editing the question, but it still doesn't explain what you want to know.  Are you trying to make butter flavor, or maple flavor?  Those are two different questions.

Comment: Thank you for clearing up what the question is about, I reopened the question. It seems that you are using two accounts, or maybe posting twice as an unregistered person. If you wish to register at least one of the accounts, you can also request a merger down the line.

Comment: Laura / Bake to. be different, thank you for your cooperation and clarification. However, we have one rule here that basically says „one question per post“. If you were asking about making flavor extracts in general, we might be able to see butter and maple as two variants of the same principle. However, you are asking about *refining* the two, which makes them two distinct issues, so those should go in different questions. I am making an unilateral decision here and take out the butter part. You are more than welcome to ask a second question - you can use the question history to copy-paste.

Comment: If you need any help in posting the second question (about butter flavor), feel free to ping me - you can reach users by typing ‘@‘ and the user name, which should also auto-complete.